# Drush can't update : Cannot redeclare system_help

Tags: drupal-6, drush

I am trying to use drush to update my drupal core but in some cases (not all) I get

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare system_help() (previously declared in /mysite/modules/system/system.module:46) in /mysite/sites/all/modules/drupal-6.22/modules/system/system.module on line 105
>   Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Regards.

Comment: After carefully reading the error message I found that I have a drupal-6.22 folder under sites/all/modules.  The problem is that if I remove that directory my site stops working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue, checked and there was inside the core module folder another module folder like:
www/module
www/module/module

Fixed the issue by reinstalling from scratch that drupal build and also upgraded my version of drush.

Comment: Well that will work.   Unfortunately I will lose all the content. If only I could change all the settings that are pointing to the internal "drupal" copy to the external one.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and it turns out I (as the system admin) had installed drush globally.  The developer had installed it as a system module inside of sites/all/modules.

I removed the sites/all/modules/drush for the site and then was able to drush up as normal.